# Play wav using MediaPlayer

Tags: android, wav

I am trying to read a wav file in raw file.

Here are the code i use:

```
MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.error);

mPlayer.start();
```

I don't know why the wav is not played?

Comment: which device are you using to play this file?

Comment: my nexus S (android 4.1)

Comment: It's supported 4.1+ http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html

Answer (score 4):

Try using `setOnCompletionListener` before the `.start` method of the `mPlayer`

```
button[i].setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View view) {

          MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.error);
          mPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

             @Override
             public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 mp.release();
             }
          });   
          mPlayer.start();
      }
});
```